# acess function in objected, nested inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, coffeescript, nested

Im trying to manage a connection instance, using a function to handle idle connection disconnect issues, using mysql database and node.js

At moment, i've got following code (coffescript):

```
mysql = require 'mysql'

handleDisconnect = () ->
  connection = mysql.createConnection
    host: 'localhost'
    user: 'root'
    password: 'passroot'
    database: 'mydb'

  connection.connect (err) ->
    if err
      console.log 'Error connecting to db: ', err
    setTimeout handleDisconnect, 2000

  connection.on 'error', (err) ->
    console.log 'db error', err
    if err.code == 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
      handleDisconnect()
    else
      throw err

  handleDisconnect.instance = connection

module.exports = handleDisconnect
```

and

```
express = require 'express'
router = express.Router()
connection = require('../database')().instance

bcrypt = require 'bcryptjs'

router.post '/', (req, res) ->
  credential = connection.escape req.body.credential
  password = connection.escape req.body.password
  res.send credential+password

module.exports = router
```

Problem is, when i try to access the route, i get following error:

Cannot read property 'escape' of undefined

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you change `handleDisconnect.instance = connection` to `@instance = connection`? It's been ages since I've done any coffeescript

Comment: The error stays the same

Comment: Stick `return @` at the end of the handleDisconnect?

Comment: neither does return @ instance = connection or @instance = connection work

Comment: As in both, or just access `connection` rather than bothering with instance, [like so](http://coffeescript.org/#try:handleDisconnect%20%3D%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%40connection%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20host%3A%20'localhost'%0A%20%20%20%20user%3A%20'root'%0A%20%20%20%20password%3A%20'passroot'%0A%20%20%20%20database%3A%20'mydb'%0A%20%20%40%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aconsole.log(handleDisconnect().connection))

Comment: Basically, your function isn't returning itself, instead it's returning the instance. So you're kinda trying to get `handleDisconnect.instance.instance`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sweeeeet :D I've just posted an answer, so if you think that fully explains it, please give that an upvote and accept too. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the final line of `handleDisconnect` is returning the instance, so you're trying to get the `instance` from `instance`, not from `handleDisconnect`. So you'll need the function to return itself at the end if you want to access properties on it.

You also want the function to be using the equivalent of "this" (`@` in coffeescript) rather than specifically referring to `handleDisconnect`.

Example code:

```
mysql = require 'mysql'

handleDisconnect = () ->
  connection = mysql.createConnection
    host: 'localhost'
    user: 'root'
    password: 'passroot'
    database: 'mydb'

  connection.connect (err) ->
    if err
      console.log 'Error connecting to db: ', err
    setTimeout handleDisconnect, 2000

  connection.on 'error', (err) ->
    console.log 'db error', err
    if err.code == 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
      handleDisconnect()
    else
      throw err

  @instance = connection
  @

module.exports = handleDisconnect
```

Although I'd personally just do the following, don't bother with "instance" at all:

1. Use `@connection` in your function
2. Scrap the `@instance = connection`
3. Get the function to return itself
4. Access it with `require('../database')().connection`.

Comment: Cheers! Work like a charm!

Comment: Ah, I used to be such a coffeescript fanboy. But then things like this remind me of why features, such as implied return statements, can be a real PITA. Glad it solved your issue nontheless

Comment: I miss arrow functions and literal templates.